# Promotion section of FAQ incorrect on all sites but SO

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, advertising, site-faq

> ### May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?
>
> Be careful, because the community frowns on overt self-promotion and tends to vote it down and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if they happen to be about your product or website, so be it. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers. Also, if a huge percentage of your posts include a mention of your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons. Our advertising rates are quite reasonable; [contact our ad sales team for details.](https://stackoverflow.com/about/contact) We also offer [free vote-based advertising for open source projects](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source-advertising)

The above comes from the [FAQ for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion), and there's nothing wrong with it.

The above is also the [the FAQ for Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion), which does not have an ad sales team, but does have a [similar but different meta question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1892/community-promotion-ads-1h-2011) that *isn't* limited to open source projects.

The above is also [the FAQ for Photography](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion), which has neither an ad sales team or the community promotion initiative.

Can this text be changed to reflect each community's situation wrt advertisement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While we are not doing paid advertisement on Stack Exchange sites *now*, we indeed want to hear from people who feel like they *want* to advertise on these sites.

Thus, the message is still relevant.